# I want to post JSON data to a particular URL so that I can read from that

Tags: javascript, json, spring-mvc

```java
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
while(rs.next()){
  HashMap<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>(columns);
  for(int i=1; i<=columns; ++i){           
    row.put(md.getColumnName(i),rs.getObject(i));
  }
  list.add(row);
}
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(list);
model.addAttribute("data", jsonarray);
```

In my JSP, I have data in JSON Format. Now, I need to post this data to another URL, so that, I can access it directly by mapping to that URL. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: This seems like something that can be easily Google'd, but we use jQuery's `$.ajax()` and such.

Answer (score 0):

Just send it as GET and it will append to the end of your URL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Plenty of ways to read it, for example start the data with a ?, import AngularJS and than use the $location.search() variable to retrieve the whole string as an object.

EDIT: AngularJS stores it as an object similar to a hashmap, which is in the format String:Value -> easy to convert to a JSON and back